# Automated Hardware/Software Test

Tags: testing, software, test, test-equipment, device

I am an Electrical Engineer and I don’t have a strong Software Engineering  background.

My problem is: I need to test several Smart home devices. For example: a door that opens and closes (also 2 different commands).

We have an App (IOS/Android) that controls the smart home devices. When the App is updated, we need to test the devices, but the test must be automated (the devices are wireless devices and are controlled by a smartphone).

How I could automate the test of all devices after the App update?

Is LabVIEW an option for the automated test?

Should I have the code of the App to execute the test in LabVIEW ?

Is there another option?

Comment: What is your budget? Your software choice is the least of your worries. For a device/unit of this type you want to send inputs to the unit and check for the proper response. You probably don't want a phone in the loop, so you need to understand the commands that the phone is sending and simulate them with a control computer. Then, you need sensors to measure the response of the unit.

Comment: If your budget is high, then National Instruments could be a good choice for hardware and software. Someone without a software background might find LabView to be a good choice to control the test. A software person generally prefers a product such as LabWindows, a more traditional software environment. If you want this project completed in a reasonable amount of time, you probably need several people, one might as well be a software expert.

Comment: Every time I’ve looked at labview I’ve hated it - but I can’t recall why. I ended up using python for all my testing needs

Comment: Consider ‘unit testing’: on the one hand you could set up a robot arm to operate a smartphone and have a real door to lock/unlock, but the unit test philosophy relies on designing your firmware and hardware in blocks that have well-defined and hopefully simple functions, you can test each block easily and have a high confidence that the system as a whole will work properly.

Comment: @Mattman944 thank you for your response, we have budget for the equipments. But the problem is that , how can I simulate the App Update (Code comands) in the drive/devices ? I know that I need to send a signal for the devices but I will need to test the Update.

Comment: @Frog is clear that I need to test it in block but how can I bring the app update to test the devices ? 
And I need to automate my test ? Which will be the best way for it ?

Comment: @Caio Miguel write as much code as you can to be platform-independent, that way you can do most of your testing on a PC (obviously this is a different architecture and so you’ll need to write code with this in mind.  You can also write some simple test cases for hardware-specific code modules, and you can test inter-device communications by passing data through a virtual ‘data pipe’.  The important thing to keep in mind is to have each function in your code do one well-defined job.